# Nesting a random factor in GLM(M)

Tags: r, glm, glmm

I want to run a GLMM in R with a random effect that is nested into one of my fixed effects.

To describe the data a little bit:

`genotype` has 24 levels, and I would like to nest this within
`origin` that has 3 levels

All these genotypes come from these 3 origins, 8 genotypes from each origin.

What would be the correct syntax for this? Should I use `/` or `:` in this case? Below is an example syntax that I have.

```r
glmmTMB(data = data, response ~ fixed A + fixed B + origin 
   +(1|origin/genotype), family = binomial)

glmmTMB(data = data, response ~ fixed A + fixed B + origin 
    +(1|origin/genotype), family = binomial)


glmmTMB(data = data, response ~ fixed A + fixed B + origin 
   +(1|origin:genotype), family = binomial)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite R forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: Your first two code examples look the same: typo?

Answer (score 2):

Your last example (`... + origin+(1|origin:genotype)`) looks correct.

- `origin` is handled as a fixed effect (possibly because you are interested in making statistical inferences about the differences between origins, or more likely because three levels of a grouping variable is usually insufficient to fit a random effect [unless you go to a Bayesian approach with regularizing priors/integration over the uncertainty]
- `origin:genotype` represents the interaction of origin and genotype, or "genotype within origin".

Also:

- `origin + (1|origin/genotype)` would be incorrect, because `(1|origin/genotype)` expands to `(1|origin) + (1|origin:genotype)`, so you would have specified `origin` redundantly as both a fixed effect (`origin`) and a random effect (`1|origin`)
- if your genotypes were explicitly labeled by origin (e.g. `A1, A2, ..., A8, B1, B2, ..., B8, ...` rather than being labeled 1-8 in each origin), then `(1|origin:genotype)` and `(1|genotype)` would be equivalent, as far as R is concerned (but you still might want to keep the formula as `(1|origin:genotype)` to make it more explicit/obvious when reading the code that genotypes are nested within origin